# FFmpeg: Looping stream of multiple files

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

Currently trying to loop a stream of audio files loaded from a .txt file:

```
 #! /bin/bash
    
        VBR="1500k"
        FPS="30"
        QUAL="ultrafast"
        YOUTUBE_URL=" rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2"
        YOUTUBE_KEY="****"
        VIDEO_SOURCE="video.mp4"
        AUDIO_ENCODER="aac"
        
        ffmpeg \
         -stream_loop -1 \
         -re \
         -i "$VIDEO_SOURCE" \
         -thread_queue_size 512 \
         -stream_loop -1 \
         -re \
         -f concat -i audiofiles.txt \
         -c:v libx264 -preset $QUAL -r $FPS -g $(($FPS *2)) -b:v $VBR -bufsize 3000k -maxrate $VBR \
         -c:a $AUDIO_ENCODER -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -pix_fmt yuv420p \
         -f flv $YOUTUBE_URL/$YOUTUBE_KEY
```

The result is that the playlist gets played once and then stops. How can I force the loop?

Comment: 1) Your command should be giving you error: `Unrecognized option 'I'`. Change `-I` to `-i`. 2) Do all of your inputs listed in `audiofiles.txt` have the same attributes (format, sample rate, channel layout, number of streams)?

Comment: 1) yes, just fixed
2) yes they are all .mp3 with the same sample rate and they all work well during the streaming test: they will loop if directly inserted in the script and played singularly but play only once if in the .txt list.

Comment: See [Is it possible to create an endless loop using concat?](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/25786)

Comment: That was the key! it works now. Maybe you want to post the last comment as an answer so I accept it and close the question. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [concat demxuer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) input text file can refer to itself to create an endless loop.

Example contents of `audio.txt`:

```
ffconcat version 1.0
file 'audio1.mp3'
file 'audio2.mp3'
file 'audio.txt'
```

The header `ffconcat version 1.0` is required for this to work.

Simple example command to continuously loop 2 audio files listed in `audio.txt` and end output duration at the same duration as `video.mp4`:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -f concat -i audio.txt -shortest output.mp4
```

Adapted from [Is it possible to create an endless loop using concat?](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/25786)